# Where to keep python class method return types?

Tags: python, typing, project-structure

I have a python module for making HTTP requests and a different one for making database calls. I'm generating typing for the 3rd API JSON response and the MongoDB entities using [dict-typer](https://github.com/ikornaselur/dict-typer).
**What is the best place to store tons of custom return data types for the class methods generated by [dict-typer](https://github.com/ikornaselur/dict-typer)?** In the same module of the method that uses them or outside?

Since usually, one method returns with a custom type, I believe the type should be tied to the method in the same module, but then it blows up the source file. Another issue is when more custom response type has some fields with the same name that conflicts.

My current solution produces many files since I move every response type to a standalone module to avoid:

- type name collisions of

  - response type
  - response field type
- blowing up the client file

```py
class AFieldType(TypedDict):
  a: str
  b: str
  ...

class AResponse(TypedDict):
  a: AFieldType
  b: str
  ...

# A partial type `AFieldType` which feels conflicting
class AFieldTypePartial1(TypedDict):
  a: str
  ...

class AFieldTypePartial2(TypedDict):
  a: str
  ...

class BResponse(TypedDict):
  a: AFieldTypePartial1
  b: str
  ...

class BVariant1Response(TypedDict):
  ...

class BVariant2Response(TypedDict):
  ...

class FooClient:
  def get_A() -> AResponse:
    pass
  def get_B() -> BResponse:
    pass
  def get_B_variant1() -> BVariant1Response:
    pass
  def get_B_variant2() -> BVariant2Response:
    pass
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are reusing the name `AFieldType` for two different classes, or why you think you need separate types for the `a` field of the two different response types.

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly. Do your requests and database share similar fields? If so, how about ARequestFieldType and ADatabaseFieldType?

Comment: I updated the description to make it a little bit cleaner. Some return types have the same field type as a different part of a whole projected DB entity.

Comment: If you want a "specific" string type to differentiate between strings for an `AReponse` and `BReponse`, you can simply define something like `AResponseStr = str` and `BResonseStr = str`, or use `typing.NewType` to provide a stronger static guarantee without too much runtime overhead.

Comment: I am unclear as to what you're looking for here: Is there a finite, known set of types at compile-time?  If so, you can use protobuf to communicate the instances. A database management system (like Django or SQLAlchemy) typically defines known classes and handles serialization & display issues. If you don't know the full set of classes at compile-time, then it sounds like you invent new classes on the fly?  If so, are the classes mere data containers? Those are efficiently communicated via JSON. If they have methods that need to be generated and stored, put those class defs' Python in the DB.

Comment: I own the schema first Mongo database schema. One nested collection, let's call `B` has different methods to serve it partially. That is the thing I wanted to represent by `BVariant1Response`. Even though the DB entity is the same, the typing is different since the nested entity is projected. **This produces a lot of type classes**. I'm wondering where should I keep these classes that bilongs to a specific method?